# Preimage of a line $u=u_{0}$ of complex function $z\mapsto z^{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let's assume that we have a complex function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $z\mapsto z^{2}$.

We want to know what is the preimage of a line $u=u_{0}$, where $u$ refers to the $uv$-plane.

First we can express our function $f$ as components
$$
\begin{cases}
u(z)&=x^2-y^2\\v(z)&=2xy.
\end{cases}
$$

Second we can express the line as $L_{u_{0}}=\{(u_{0},v)\mid v\in\mathbb{R} \}$.

Now, what is the preimage $f^{-1}\big[L_{u_{0}} \big]=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid f(z)\in L_{u_{0}} \}$?

What I have been trying is solving a system of equations

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2 &= u_{0}\\2xy&=v,
\end{cases}
$$

but with bad luck. Time has passed since I last time have been doing this so please be gentle. I need a hint.

---

After discovering how blind I am I will announce that the preimage is indeed hyperbola.

Also if the case would be $(u,v_{0})$ then preimage would be a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $x^2 -y^2 =u_0 $ derives a hyperbola, so the preimage is this hyperbola on $oxy$ plane.

Comment: But what about the $v(z)$ component, doesn't it have any role in this?